# Code-First Auto-Create SQL Server database on application start

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

As the title says, I want my application automatically create the database on application start. But, I would like that on the production server. I have a dynamic connection string generator class which handles the `Initial Catalog` value. I also have a database user on the server which has `DbCreator` and `SysAdmin` roles configured. I am using that database user on the dynamic connection string the app is creating on the app start phase.

I still couldn't manage to see an auto-created database on the server, with that configuration. Also, not being able to find any production scenario examples for `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` on my searches, a question came up: *Did I figure that out wrong?*

Is the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer works only for `LocalDB`?

Comment: Have you setup migrations? Migrations make it a lot easier (and will be performed on initial access to the DB). And to answer your question, no they do not only work on LocalDb.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to change "CreateDatabaseIfNotExists" to "MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" and provide some initial data on the configuration class?

Comment: Well, a database initializer is still going to be performed, just migrations make it easier to manage deltas (and anything beyond that initial create becomes a headache, not to mention the potential of data loss). That aside, as long as you've defined a DbInitializer (either through the web.config `<entityFramework>` node or through the static `Database.SetInitializer` method, the first read will fire off the initializer. The only really gain you get on App_Start is avoiding a one-time warmup.

Comment: The only thing I need in this situation is to get rid of the need for connecting to the production server (rdc or sms) to create a new database. I am planning to remove the connection string which is creating the db immediately after the db creation and create another one with a DbUser which has only DbReader role. Leaving a connection string which has a DbUser with SysAdmin or DbCreator roles on the web.config is too risky for me. Would you like to sum it up and create an answer? I will try that first thing in the morning and write back my experiences. Thank you for your comments.